# How can i compare queues in cpp?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, queue, priority-queue

i need to compare the size of 10 queues and determine the least one in size to insert the next element in

creating normal if statements will take A LOT of cases

so is there any way to do it using a queue of queue for example or an array of queues ?

note :
i will need to compare my queues based on 2 separate things in 2 situations
1- based on size ( number of nods in it )
2- based on the total number of the data in the nods in it ( which i have a separate function to calculate )

Comment: What does the "size" refer to? Number of elements? Some amount of specific data in the elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that

```
std::queue<int> queue1;
std::vector<std::queue<int> > queues; // Declare a vector of queue 

queues.push_back(queue1);       // Add all of your queues to the vector 
// insert other queue here ... 

std::vector<std::queue<int> >::const_iterator minItt = queues.begin(); // Get the first queue in the vector 

// Iterate over all of the queues in the vector to fin the one with the smallest size 
for(std::vector<std::queue<int> >::const_iterator itt = ++minItt; itt != queues.end(); ++itt) 
{ 
    if(itt->size() < minItt->size()) 
        minItt = itt; 
}
```

If it's not fast enough for you, you could always make your search in the vector with std::for_each() and a functor.

Comment: so assumin that my queues are A,B,C,D,C

will the minItt returns the queue it self ( ie . A ) or will it return its value ?

Comment: 'minItt' is an iterator over the vector of queue. You can use it as a pointer (with the '->' operator) and have access to your queue that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a heap, where the key is the size of each queue.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is a vector of queues. Iterate through the vector to find the queue with the fewest entries.